# Toggling(or Flashing) a particular cell in a Table for some time frame

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have created a table in Html and I would like to make a particular cell to be flashing(on and off ) sort of.Can you please let me know if it is possible using javascript.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h4>Two rows and three columns:</h4>
      <table border="1" width="100%" height="400" align="top">
        <tr style="height: 1">
          <td>
            <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100" align="top">
              <tr>
                 <td  bgcolor="#FFFF00">1-1</td> <!-- R1C1 Yellow -->
                 <td>1-2</td> 
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>1-3</td>
                 <td>1-4</td>
               </tr>
             </table>
          </td> 
          <td>
            <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100" align="top">
               <tr>
                 <td>2-1</td>
                 <td>2-2</td> 
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>2-3</td>
                 <td>2-4</td>
               </tr>
             </table>
          <td>
            <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100" align="top">
               <tr>
                 <td>3-1</td>
                 <td>3-2</td> 
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>3-3</td>
                 <td>3-4</td>
               </tr>
           </table>
         </td> 
       </tr>
       <tr style="vertical-align: top">
         <td>
           <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100">
               <tr>
                 <td>4-1</td>
                 <td>4-2</td> 
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>4-3</td>
                 <td>4-4</td>
               </tr>
          </table>
         <td>
           <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100">
               <tr>
                 <td>5-1</td>
                 <td>5-2</td> 
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>5-3</td>
                 <td>5-4</td>
               </tr>
             </table>
          <td> 
             <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100">
               <tr>
                 <td>6-1</td>
                 <td>6-2</td> 
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>6-3</td>
                 <td>6-4</td>
               </tr>
             </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the below image , say Row1 and col 1 ,  Is it possible in javascript or html to make it flash/blink in yellow?   Thanks
[image: image file]

**UPDATE**
I'm able to flash the cells , but currently all of them flash randomly, though i have the time as same. But i want all of them to flash together(At the same time) and go off , then again flash and go off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a javascript function that changes the background color of the desired cell.
Further you can use setInterval() function to call the function after a fixed amount of time.

```
var flag = true;
function changeColor () {
    if(flag==true){
        document.getElementById("yourId").style.background="yourColor 1";
        flag=false;
    }
    else if (flag==false){
    document.getElementById("yourId").style.background="yourcolor 2";
    flag = true;
    }
}
setInterval("changeColor()", timeinmillisec);
```

Comment: If you have complete sample, can you please post it ,I'm very new to Javascript

Comment: can you please explain how the javascript function is getting called here ?

Comment: Here the function changeColor() finds the element with id=="yourId".
Now it checks the value of flag variable if its value is true it changes the background color of that element and sets the flag's value to false.
Next time when it it called it finds flag's value==false so it again changes the background color of the element.
The setInterval() function calls any specified function after every particular interval of time. In this case the function to be called is changeColor(); So after every few milliseconds the function is called again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setTimeout` for deferring execution of some code for a certain number of milliseconds. To get a flashing behavior, you could set the style to whatever it currently isn't (I'm setting classes in my example, but you're free to implement it any other way of course), and set a new timeout for the next alteration.

[My example](http://jsfiddle.net/kjh8P/).

```
var elapsed = 0;
var interval = 250;
var duration = 3000;

function toggle(element) {
    var newClass = element.className == 'highlight' ? '' : 'highlight';
    element.className = newClass;
    elapsed += interval;

    if(elapsed < duration)
        setTimeout(function() { toggle(element); }, interval);
}

var element = document.getElementById('cell');
toggle(element);​
```

Here, I'm using the variables `duration` to set the desired duration of the entire flashing animation, `elapsed` to keep track of how long the flashing has been going on (threshold to be compared to `duration`), and `interval` to set the distance between each flash / toggle.

The `toggle` function sets the class name to `highlight` or nothing at all, depending on whatever it currently isn't, to get an alternating behavior. Given that the `duration` has not been exceeded, `toggle` is set to fire again after `interval` milliseconds.

Note that I'm using `getElementById` to identify the cell of interest. If this is not appropriate for you, you could use `getElementsByTagName`. For instance `table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td')[2]` will get the third column of the first row in a table.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign it an id you can use `setTimeout()` to change it's background after some time like so:

```
function changeColour() {
    document.getElementById("myId").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
}
setTimeout("changeColour()", 2000); // Turn it yellow in 2 seconds
```

I think you get the general idea, you can improve the code above to make it blink.