# Flashing rows or Toggling in a table cell after clicking it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Working on some javascript code by following the example of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9616016/8542834). But somehow it is not getting to repeat the colors after clicking it. Can anyone guide me how to approach this issue? (excuse the non-english identifiers)

The HTML code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="lab5_2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lab5_2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <p id="vlerat"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is:

```
td {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue;}
```

The Javascript code is:

```
var tableResult;

function start() {

    tableResult = "<table border='1' align='center'>";

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        tableResult += "<tr>";

        for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            tableResult += "<td id='" + i + j + "' onclick='save(id)'></td>"
        }
        tableResult += "</tr><br>";
    }
    tableResult += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = tableResult;
}

function changeColor(test) {
    var flag = true;
    if (flag === true) {
        document.getElementById(test).style.background = "#ff0000";
        flag = false;
    } else if (flag === false) {
        document.getElementById(test).style.background = "#ffff00";
        flag = true;
    }
}

function save(id) {
    setInterval(changeColor(id), 110);
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "But somehow it is not getting to repeat the colors after clicking it."?

Comment: @Highdef I mean that after i click it, it just stays the color color blue, and nothing changes.

Comment: Oh, okay got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `flag is getting initialized as true again and again` as soon as it enters the function. Only this part of the code is being invoked :

```
if (flag === true) {
    document.getElementById(test).style.background = "#ff0000";
    flag = false;
  }
```

That's why the color was stuck to red.To fix it, just `declare it out of the function` as demonstrated and it works fine. Hope, it helps.

```js
var tableResult;
var flag = true;

function start() {

  tableResult = "<table border='1' align='center'>";

  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    tableResult += "<tr>";

    for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
      tableResult += "<td id='" + i + j + "' onclick='save(id)'></td>"
    }
    tableResult += "</tr><br>";
  }
  tableResult += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = tableResult;
}

function changeColor(test) {

  if (flag === true) {
    document.getElementById(test).className += "color";
  }

}


function save(id) {
  setInterval(changeColor(id), 110);
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.color {
  animation: colorchange 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes colorchange {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<p id="vlerat"></p>
```

Comment: There are no more errors at least, so thank you! But the thing is that i need to click it again to turn yellow and it does not pulse from red to yellow and vice versa on it's own... I guess you can check that by running the code snippet here.

Comment: Also, after some little debugging, it seems that after the first setInterval() exectues, the code jumps into some VM### that shows undefined

Comment: @minus.273 I have made some modifications. does this work for you?

Comment: i just tried it, the change happens, but it does not repeat by itself...

Comment: @minus.273 you want it ongoing as infinitely?

Comment: Yes, i suppose i was not very clear wasn't i? :/  Because at the example i have linked, it repeats infinetely, doesn't it?

Comment: @minus.273 Modified

Comment: It works like a gem! Thank you very much, but i have an additional question: can i make it work somehow without the css?

Comment: I'd say it would be a hassle with settimeinterval as the animation using CSS is more easy and clean functioning. But I think you can add the CSS itself using javascript but its a bit complex.

Comment: I understand. Much appreciated! All the best :)

Comment: @minus.273 No problem :)